# add color to css -webkit-box-reflect instead of image

Tags: css, reflection

I want to make to reflection to a **solid colour reflection with fade off at the bottom** instead of the image itself, is it possible?

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/iGrmq

```
img{            
  -webkit-box-reflect: below -2px
  -webkit-gradient(linear,
                center top,
                center bottom,
                from(transparent),
                to(white)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for this? **[Live demo (click).](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dkKLq)**

**Sample Markup:**

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://static.jquery.com/files/rocker/images/logo_jquery_215x53.gif" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
body{
  background: black;
}

img {            
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px;
}
.img-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.img-container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,
    transparent 0%,
    #FFF 82%
  )
}
```